# Use textarea input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script that uses the input.

```
<textarea id="textareabox" name="textarea1" placeholder="Start here..."></textarea>

function hintbutton4() {
    document.getElementById("textareabox").innerHTML = 'ID=textareabox';
}
```

I've got this, but I don't know how to grab the text as input...
How can I do it? What should I search for?

I want the input from the text area used in the script in the last part 'ID=textareabox'. That's all.

Comment: Like most form fields, there is no `innerHTML` on a [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement), just a `value` property.

Comment: do you want to put text into the text area?

Comment: No I want to use the text in the text area in my javascript

Comment: If you're trying to change the text typed into textarea try:
    document.getElementById("textareabox").value = 'INPUT';

Also see here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp

Comment: Use this fiddle to know what you want... https://jsfiddle.net/shemdani/rwzx8j50/1/

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Also I highly doubt the upvotes on either the question and/or answer aren't by sockpuppets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example using pure JavaScript.

Essentially, from what I understand, you are trying to populate a textarea with JavaScript as well as get the value.

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWyOMq

**JavaScript**

```
function getText() {
    var text = document.getElementById("textareabox").value;
    alert(text);
}

function setText() {
    var text = document.getElementById("textareabox").value = 'Hello, World!';

}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div>
    <textarea id="textareabox" name="textarea1" placeholder="Start here..."></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Get Text" onclick="getText()" />
    <input type="button" value="Set Text" onclick="setText()" />
</div>
```